# Photoshop - Increase Number in Text and Save as that Text

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I am looking for a way to make me able to change/save X images so i don't have to do it manually.

So the only thing i want to change is a Text Layer which is called: Part 1#

I simply want to change the Text to Part 2# (3,4,5,6 etc).

And for every change i want to save it in .PNG as "Part 1#" "Part 2#", so the same name as the Text Layer.

I can't seem to find any information regarding this entire procedure, only automated processes of changing 1 thing, not the 2 simultaneously.

Can't provide any tries either as i haven't been able to really do anything, though i have looked around at the script, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hmm, you can't do it with photoshop but you can write an app that renders the bg with the increased number.

Comment: You want to change the name of the layer, or the content of the text, or both? (I think you *can* do this photoshop!!)

Comment: I want to change the Text Layer "Text", so the change is Visible, changing the "Variable" name doesn't matter as it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after 9 seconds of searching on the interweb, I found this script:

```
 function sfwPNG24(saveFile){
 var pngOpts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb;
 pngOpts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG
 pngOpts.PNG8 = false;
 pngOpts.transparency = true;
 pngOpts.interlaced = false;
 pngOpts.quality = 100;
 activeDocument.exportDocument(new File(saveFile),ExportType.SAVEFORWEB,pngOpts);
 }

 /*
 Incrementing a number inside a text layer then Saving it in PNG
 */

 var layer = activeDocument.layers[0];

 if (layer.kind == 'LayerKind.TEXT') {
 for (var i=1; i < 7; i++) {
 layer.textItem.contents = i.toString();
 sfwPNG24( 'path/where/you/want/to/save/your/files'+ i +'.png');
 };
 };
```

Courtesy of juliend2 - https://gist.github.com/juliend2/757422

Just change the path bit at the end and save it as a .js file somewhere, then go to File... -> Scripts -> Browse... and hey presto

Comment: This does work as expected, is it possible to prevent "-" when you write Spaces in a string?

Thanks

Comment: "Well, after 9 seconds of searching" Does that provide any value to your answer?